# DataFrame conditional update of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm looking for a more elegant and Pythonic code for the following problem:

In column **start** I have a release week for every item (from 1 to 4), I add **W1,..., W4** columns with ones.

Next I want to update columns in this way (basically, replace the ones in the release week and the week before and week after with zeros):

```
   start  W1  W2  W3  W4
      1   0   0   1   1
      2   0   0   0   1
      3   1   0   0   0
      4   1   1   0   0
```

I'm doing it right now with this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'start': [1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in range(1,4+1):
    df['W'+str(i)] = 1

for index, i in enumerate(df['start']):
    if i==1:
        df.ix[index, 'W1'] = 0
        df.ix[index, 'W2'] = 0
    elif i==4:
        df.ix[index, 'W3'] = 0
        df.ix[index, 'W4'] = 0
    else:
        df.ix[index, 'W'+str(i-1)] = 0
        df.ix[index, 'W'+str(i)] = 0
        df.ix[index, 'W'+str(i+1)] = 0
```

Comment: `map` is slower. Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solution with map is slower but for me more readable (personal taste) and shorter. Also it don't use numpy.
One thing: when I added more rows, it returns error. Probably, there is an easy fix, but I didn't look for.
Once more than for your help and for sharing different approach.

Comment: You can upvote all solutions you found helpful. By the way, you should compare the performances of the solution you accepted v/s mine... you'll find there is a staggering difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your df

```
df = df.astype(int)

start   W1  W2  W3  W4
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   1   1   1   1
2   3   1   1   1   1
3   4   1   1   1   1
```

You can apply map to df to recalculate values using the function:

```
def func(pivot):
    return [1 if abs(col-pivot) > 1 else 0 for col in [1,2,3,4]]
```

This was my first option for map, unnecessarily complex:

```
df['W1'], df['W2'], df['W3'], df['W4'] = zip(*df['start'].map(func))
```

This one, from @QuantChristo, is much better

```
weeks = ['W1','W2','W3','W4']
df[weeks] = df['start'].map(func)
```

In both cases you get df:

```
start   W1  W2  W3  W4
0   1   0   0   1   1
1   2   0   0   0   1
2   3   1   0   0   0
3   4   1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've slightly changed code to less intimitading to me (no zip and *)
`def func(pivot):

    return [1 if abs(col-pivot) > 1 else 0 for col in range(1,4+1)]

weeks = ['W1','W2','W3','W4']
df[weeks] = df['start'].map(func)`

Comment: In fact, looks simpler and better. I updated the answer to take your code into account

Comment: With lambda function, it could even be one-liner (or two-liner if you count weeks definition).
One advantage of weeks, is that you can easily add more weeks (e.g. 52) with list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Perform broadcasted numpy comparison to obtain a mask, and just set the values at the corresponding indices to `0`.

```
df.set_index('start', inplace=True)
```

```
i = df.index.values
j = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)[:, None]

df.values[(i - 1 <= j) & (j <= i + 1)] = 0
df

       W1  W2  W3  W4
start                
1       0   0   1   1
2       0   0   0   1
3       1   0   0   0
4       1   1   0   0
```

---

**Details**

```
i
array([1, 2, 3, 4]) 

j 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

First, compute the mask -

```
m = (i - 1 <= j) & (j <= i + 1)
m

array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The mask `m` is for the entire dataframe. Just index on `values` and set the cells to `0` -

```
df.values[m] = 0
```

To reset the index, use `reset_index` -

```
df.reset_index()

   start  W1  W2  W3  W4
0      1   0   0   1   1
1      2   0   0   0   1
2      3   1   0   0   0
3      4   1   1   0   0
```